# How do I get and install an SSL certificate on a Bitnami image on Amazon EC2?

Tags: apache, security-certificate, amazon-aws, openssl

I need to get an SSL certificate installed on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance that runs the [bitnami image](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/). I watched [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCeQqXfUt6A) on how to do it but during the video he creates the CSR and then pastes it into his SSL certificate application online.

I have contacted an SSL provider and they have said they create the CSR during checkout and then give me the files. So does this mean I do not need to generate a CSR on the server and I will simply be able to copy over the two existing certificate files?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that means they will have to give you a private key for your server and the public certificate files if you aren't generating the CSR. If that is the case you would **not** need to generate a CSR. However you would also need to install the private key. This doesn't sound like the typical approach as the private key would have to be transferred to you.

**Typical SSL Scenario Includes:**

1. You generate the CSR and a private KEY on your server.
2. You submit the CSR to the SSL provider.
3. You install the Public Certificate file on your server and its matches up with the private key.